# How to select ranks to search for CP decomposition of 4-mode tensor of experimental gene expression data?

Tags: decomposition, tensor

I have a sparse (0.625 percent non-zero occupancy) data [tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor) with shape `(118, 16, 5009, 10)`. I would like to try exploring the data using [CP decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_rank_decomposition). The modes represent sample, timepoint, gene ID, and an experimental condition, and the entries are levels of gene [transcription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_(biology)) (RNASeq).

The [tensorly implementation](http://tensorly.org/stable/modules/generated/tensorly.decomposition.CP.html) I am using requires that I provide the rank as an input, which is normal for such implementations. Naturally I could perform a search of different ranks to see what patterns show up in the factor loadings, but are there principles or heuristics to decide what maximum rank I should search up to?

---

In my case I ran out of storage at rank 11 decomposition (while using a memory view of a temporary file), giving the following error.

`numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 325. TiB for an array with shape (9456992, 9456992) and data type float32`

The exponential scaling of the amount space required is quickly prohibitive even when using virtual memory. But I am still interested in this question in broad terms. I may have smaller data sets in the future where I would be able to check much higher ranks than [1,10].